# Getting post of azure Logic app to Data Factory

Tags: azure

I need to get the body of the post request from azure logic app to Data factory. How do I get the request body in Data Factory from Azure Logic App??

In Data Factory, under azure function, what do I have for body as dynamic content? I've tried `@activity('body')`. That doesnt work.

Here's the flow:

Logic App -> POST request -> Data Factory -> Function POST (body?)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot trigger an ADF pipeline with a body. As a workaround, you can trigger the logic app from ADF. This activity is by default asynchronous. You will need to do this synchronously. You can do this by adding a response at the end of the logic app as shown below.
[image]

Your Pipeline can then trigger your function as the next step using the response from the Logic app trigger. In my case, the response I'm passing from the logic app to ADF and then to my Function is "This is some test response".
[image]

Comment: how does web1 receive the response though?

Comment: The response step in logic apps responds back to the ADF pipeline with the response body. I have not included the actual API call in my screenshot. You will need to include that and then send the response of that back to ADF via the response step.

Comment: Hi @jaimers, have you checked my answer? If it answers your questions, kindly mark it as the answer so this question can be closed.